# OFDM Preamble Ripple Structure in Frequency Domain

Tags: ofdm, preamble

After performing a time and frequency tuning of a signal, and plotting the result in frequency domain(abs value), the following ripple structure can be witnessed.

[image]

The extracted bits are LFSR sequence(row wise bellow).

0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1

BPSK modulation is used.
Total number of SCs used in Preamble - 432.

[image]

Seems that this structure is intended by design.
Wondered what may be the reason for such preamble design.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How long is the transmitter's DFT? To me, this doesn't look like a typical OFDM signal's spectral shape *at all*, unless you're considering some low-subcarrier-count OFDM signal with some extremely oversampling observation DFT.

Comment: The extracted LFSR sequence length is 418 bins --> DFT size is 512. The up sampled symbol size is 3657. Every second bin in the relevant range is zero due to concatenation of 2 preamble waveforms.

Comment: Hm, the LFSR sequence isn't very long. You'd normally use that to make a pseudorandom noise sequence as white as possible. Could you give us info about the subcarrier modulation, the LFSR coefficients, and the number of OFDM subcarriers (by editing your question), please?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't the result of a poorly designed interpolation or decimation filter? Unless the transmitter knows the channel gains (and can therefore perform water-filling), I don't know why anyone would do this on purpose.

Comment: This is a pure signal brought to BaseBand. No filters were applied. Doing the same with the training sequence symbol, yielded the expected OFDM-like, flat response, as can be seen below: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_qN8nR8P1vZcUNaRU9ZZjF3T2M/view?usp=sharing