# Derive the LFSR sequence from demodulated bitstream

Tags: ofdm, demodulation, lfsr

I'm new here and hope to have good feedback from you.

I'm trying to blindly demodulate an RF signal and managed to get a sequence of bits for a preamble. After some research, I'm in fact exactly in the same situation as this guy:

[OFDM Preamble Ripple Structure in Frequency Domain](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/40725/ofdm-preamble-ripple-structure-in-frequency-domain)

My question is: given a bit sequence, how can you derive the LFSR sequence (and initial seed) like he seems to have done here:

https://www.dsprelated.com/thread/2716/semi-blind-ofdm-channel-estimation

Thank you !

Comment: Can you clarify what is the difference between "bit sequence" and "LFSR sequence"? Do you mean the LFSR that produced the bit sequence?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I'm off for a few days. Yes I wanted to say: how to find the generating LFSR polynom and seed given a demodulated bitstream

Comment: Dear all, I'm still stuck with that. I've derived a similar sequence than the one described in the referenced post but I still don't see how to find the corresponding generating polynom (apart from brute force ?). Is that even possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can! Given an Nth order polynomial generator, with 2N consecutive samples we can create N equations with N unknowns for the LFSR polynomial which you can then solve as a system of simultaneous equations. This would require matrix inversion in GF(2) to do directly but instead thanks to the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm this can be solved iteratively and very efficiently.  For further details of the algorithm including pseudo-code see [this Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%E2%80%93Massey_algorithm)

Comment: Just a minor comment: If we _know_ that the LFSR has degree $N$, then there are only $N-1$ coefficients that need to be determined ($x_0$ and $x_{N}$ are known to have value $1$). The advantage of the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm is that it finds the  _shortest_ LFSR that generates the given bitstream.  If the unknown LFSR that _actually_ generated the bit stream is of length $N$, then the B-M algorithm finds it after examining $2N$ bits of the bitstream. If more bits are available, further iterations of the algorithm merely confirm the result.

Comment: To continue my previous comment, if the number of bits $2s$ in the bitstream is less than _twice_ the length of the LFSR that actually generated the bitstream, then the Berlekamp-Massey algorithm finds the shortest LFSR that can generate these $2s$ bits.  This synthesized LFSR rarely has any similarity to the actual LFSR; in particular, the length of the synthesized LFSR is often close to $2s$. This is in accordance with complexity theory which says that the shortest program to print an arbitrary sequence of length $M$ is of length $M+c$ where $c$ is a constant.  In other words,.....

Comment: .... for _arbitrary_ sequences of length $M$, it is easiest to just store the sequence and print it out (the $c$ is the length of the `printf` command or equivalent) than to write an elaborate C++ program to somehow _calculate_ the sequence and then print  it out.

Comment: This would be useful for a (start up)[https://github.com/nihalpasham/google_pay_ultrasound_tokens/blob/master/code/examples_glfsr..py].